# Illustrator - Set EPS Version from CS6 default to Legacy CS(x)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, illustration, save

I have recently upgraded my version of Illustrator to CS6 but have run into a problem. I batch create EPS files for print and then hand them on to a supplier. They however don't have CS6, but CS5. Rather than batch creating all of the files and then individually re-opening them and changing the EPS Version manually, is there an alternative/way to set the file version default?

Or is there another alternative?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the version of the EPS in the save step of any action. Then run the batch.

If you record the save step as [format] eps, then choose [version] Illustrator CS5 (v15), that will be saved in the action.